# How do I get os.getcwd() to Act Identical from .py File and Run(Win+R)

Tags: python, windows, directory

I have a Python script and I use `os.getcwd`
When I run it from "run"(windows+r) it goes to my user profile.
when I run it from the .py file it goes to "C:\python34", which is what I want.
How to I get them to do the same thing, which is to go to my Python folder.

**script:**

```
#!python3
import os
current=os.getcwd()
os.startfile(current)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information provided for me to know why you're getting inconsistent results. I can only guess.

I do know that you're not going to get what you want using `os.getcwd()`. In Windows, when using the `Run` dialog, it uses the `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable to set the **C**urrent **W**orking **D**irectory. If you execute the script from a different directory, `os.getcwd()` will return the directory you're in *not* the directory the script is in.

I would suggest using something like the following to accomplish your goal. It should open up Explorer passing in the folder where Python is installed (the version you're executing the script with):

```
#!python3
import os, sys
os.startfile(sys.prefix)
```